# HQL join returns only first two rows

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to join two tables and fetch all rows from an sql database using a hibernate query. I have two mapping files Offer.hmb.xml and Product.hbm.xml. In my Products class I have this function:

```
public List<Product> getProducts() {
    factory = (new Configuration()).configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Product q = new Product();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Product p JOIN p.offers o where p.offerID = o.offerID or p.offerID = null"); 
    List<Product> list =  query.list();
    Iterator<Product> iter = list.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Product product = iter.next();
        System.out.println(product);
    }
```

Product mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="shoppingbasket.Product" table="products">
    <id name="productID" type="integer" access="field">
        <column name="ProductID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="offerID" type="java.lang.Integer" access="field">
        <column name="OfferID" />
    </property>
    <property name="productName" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="ProductName" length="40" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="unitPrice" type="java.math.BigDecimal" access="field">
        <column name="UnitPrice"/>
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="offers" class="shoppingbasket.Offer" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Offer mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="shoppingbasket.Offer" table="offers">
    <id name="offerID" type="integer" access="field">
        <column name="OfferID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="offerDescription" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="OfferDescription" length="60" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="shortDescription" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="ShortDescription" length="10" not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="TFTPOTGroup" type="java.lang.Integer" access="field">
        <column name="TFTPOTGroup" length="4" not-null="false" default="null"/>
    </property>
    <property name="discountPercentage" type="java.lang.Double" access="field">
        <column name="DiscountPercentage"  not-null="false" default="null"/>
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The query runs but only returns the first two rows however if I convert the query to SQL and run it in phpmyadmin it returns all rows. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Java and HQL any pointers/help would be appreciated

Comment: please let me know if any more info is required

Comment: show us the mapping of product and offer

Comment: added into question

Comment: the `join p.offers` bit only works if you add the relation to `Offer`

Comment: have added it to Offer but still getting the same result